# css3 animation does't work on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I'm making a moving svg image with pure HTML & CSS animations.
It works fine on all browsers excepts for IE, According to this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) CSS3 animation should work fine in IE10 or 11. I tried many ways, add prefix, meta tags, bring the @keyframes to top ... but it just refuses to work. I searched for some solutions here in Stackoverflow, but so far nothing seems to be good. For example this is one piece of my CSS:

```
@-ms-keyframes moving-cloud2 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(400px, -35px);
    fill: #f2f2f2;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(200px, -35px);
  }
}
```

You can see the rest [here](http://codepen.io/June259/pen/LkQmyB?editors=1100).

Hope I'll be answered. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using MacOS so I use virtual box to confirm the page in IE9,10,11.

Comment: see if it helps : https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811744/ie11-bug-with-implementation-of-css-transforms-in-svg